# Using (e) to select specific HTML divs in a class list

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a calculator I'm working on which has 16 unique buttons to input equations. Each button has a class of "button" in the HTML, assigned to the DOM const "button".

```
<div id="number7" class= "button">
  <h2>7</h2>
</div>
<div id="number8" class= "button">
  <h2>8</h2>
</div>

const button = document.querySelectorAll('.button);
button.forEach(but => {
  but.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    equation.textContent = e.target...... <!-- here's where I'm confused -->
  };
};
```

e.target returns the div and the h2 or only the h2, depending on where the element was clicked.
I've got it working with ids, except the code is nearly 100 lines.

How can I implement e in my program to return the unique text of the clicked div's h2?

Comment: `e.target.textContent.strip()`

Comment: You can also change your selector to `.button h2` to just match the nested `h2` elements.

Comment: Don't use `<div><h2>` if all you need is actually `<button type="button">` Semantics and accessibility matter

Comment: What is `equation` ? Some input? Could you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, stop using `Event.target` without `.closest()` - well, unless you really, really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

hei, i appreciate what you are doing but don't code like that.. you will find that it is very inefficient and time consuming. this is simple calculator function, you can try code like this. i didn explain, you can figure out by yourself. it will be good practice for you.

```js
const n_calcMonitor = document.getElementById('calc_monitor');

function calc(val){

  let curval = n_calcMonitor.innerHTML;
  
  if( val == 'c' ){ curval = ""; }
  else if( val == 'backspace' ){ curval = curval.slice(0,-1); }
  else if( val == '=' ){ curval = eval(curval); }
  else{
    curval += val;
  }
  
  n_calcMonitor.innerHTML = curval;
}
```

```html
<div id="calc_monitor"></div>
<hr />
<button onclick="calc('c')">C</button>
<button onclick="calc('backspace')">Bs</button>
<button onclick="calc('+')">+</button>
<button onclick="calc('=')">=</button>
<button onclick="calc('*')">*</button>
<button onclick="calc('/')">/</button><br />
<button onclick="calc('1')">1</button>
<button onclick="calc('2')">2</button>
<button onclick="calc('3')">3</button><br />
<button onclick="calc('4')">4</button>
<button onclick="calc('5')">5</button>
<button onclick="calc('6')">6</button><br />
<button onclick="calc('7')">7</button>
<button onclick="calc('8')">8</button>
<button onclick="calc('9')">9</button><br />
<button onclick="calc('0')">0</button>
<!-- you can add more as you want -->
```

Comment: Thanks you for the input. Essentially, I'd like to do as you described in a condensed manner in order to save space in my code, without having to specify every single button in the DOM. So far, (e) seems like the correct approach, or reworking the html.

Comment: You are free to choose. Keep going <3